# JWT authentication. Use "Bearer_$tokenValue" or "Bearer $tokenValue"?

Tags: jwt, http-headers

JWT authentication. Use "Bearer_$tokenValue" or "Bearer $tokenValue"? Is there any standard?

Answer (score 1):

In the Authorization header it should be:

```
Authorization: Bearer $tokenValue
```

See [rfc6750/section 2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.1)